# Oracle Fusion Order Demo Application

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-soa

I got this error while doing `FOD`

```
**Message:**
**WARNING:** Failed to validate the xml content. SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/11/jps-config-11_1.xsd must have even number of URI's. Location: unavailable.



**In Apache Ant:**

Buildfile: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\Ant\build.xml

init:
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\Ant\classes

setProperties:

createDatabase:

refreshSchema:
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 11 of 11 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
     [echo] Warning: An unlocked database user 'FOD' has been created, with create session, table, and sequence privileges.

createSchemaObjects:
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\createFODSchemaObjects.sql
      [sql] 489 of 489 SQL statements executed successfully

createSequenceTriggers:
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\createSequenceTriggers.sql
      [sql] 20 of 20 SQL statements executed successfully

populateTables:
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 4 of 4 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
     [echo] Demo Options Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES.sql
      [sql] 5 of 5 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Available Languages Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 244 of 244 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 244 of 244 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 244 of 244 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 244 of 244 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 244 of 244 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
     [echo] Country Codes Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 66 of 66 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 66 of 66 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 66 of 66 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 66 of 66 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
      [sql] 66 of 66 SQL statements executed successfully
   [delete] Deleting: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\SQLRunner1305391231.sql
     [echo] Lookup Codes Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\ADDRESSES.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\DISCOUNTS_BASE.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\MEMBERSHIPS_BASE.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\SHIPPING_OPTIONS_BASE.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\SUPPLIERS.sql
      [sql] 173 of 173 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Addresses, Memberships, Discounts, Shipping Options and Suppliers Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\DISCOUNT_TRANSLATIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\ELIGIBLE_DISCOUNTS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\MEMBERSHIP_TRANSLATIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\PERSONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\SHIPPING_OPTION_TRANSLATIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\WAREHOUSES.sql
      [sql] 117 of 117 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Persons, Warehouses, Discount Translations, Shipping Option Translations, and Eligible Discounts Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\ADDRESS_USAGES.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\CUSTOMER_IDENTIFICATIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\PAYMENT_OPTIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_BASE.sql
      [sql] 197 of 197 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Address Usages, Customer Identifications, Payment Options, Product Categories, and Orders Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\CATEGORY_TRANSLATIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\CUSTOMER_INTERESTS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\ORDERS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\PRODUCTS_BASE.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\WAREHOUSE_STOCK_LEVELS.sql
      [sql] 425 of 425 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Products, Warehouse Stock Levels, Coupon Usages, Categories, and Customer Interests Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\ALTER_TABLES.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\COUPON_USAGES.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\HELP_TRANSLATIONS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\ORDER_ITEMS.sql
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\DataScripts\PRODUCT_TRANSLATIONS.sql
      [sql] 165 of 165 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Coupon Usages, Product Translations, Order Items, and Help Translations Created
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\PackageScripts\user_context.sql
      [sql] 2 of 2 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] USER_CONTEXT Package Created

createIndexes:
      [sql] Executing resource: C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\Scripts\createIndexes.sql
      [sql] 2 of 2 SQL statements executed successfully
     [echo] Indexes Created

compileImagesApp:
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\classes

BUILD FAILED
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\Ant\build.xml:51: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\JDeveloper\mywork\FusionOrderDemo1\11.1.1.6\Infrastructure\DBSchema\build.xml:319: C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jlib not found.

Total time: 1 minute 7 seconds
```

Comment: And what did you do to try to rectify it, or research the causes?

Answer (score 0):

> > C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\jlib not found.

Did you set the right properties in the Ant build file?
Are you sure you are using the right FOD for the version of JDeveloper you are using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks a lot to Shay Shmeltzer.

Previously I am also having same problem when I was using jDeveloper 12c. It is working with only jDeveloper 11.1.2.1.

See note in this page  [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/index-095536.html)